# Stuck with Google Maps (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

Good Afternoon guys! I am building an angular app with google maps API that takes the user's current location and then displays the nearest 20 coffee shops to them. I have found some test code to implement before I try to implement my changes. However, no matter what I do I just keep getting a 404 error on the landing page. I have been stuck on this for days and I can't find answer's anywhere. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong or does anyone know of any Google Maps (Angular) nearby search tutorials that I can learn from? I'm really stuck here. Thanks in advance guys.

Edit:1 - I ran npm i @types/googlemaps on CLI as well! The one error on component.html is coming from the sanitization not being recognized.

[file path displaying model and components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsSgt.png)

[picture of what is displayed on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEv6K.png)

```html
user-landing-page.component.html

<div class="page-container">
  <div class="slider-container">
      <div class="external-neighbourhood">
          <div class="heading" style="margin-left: 1rem;">
              <h5>NEIGHBORHOODS</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="no-image" *ngIf="neighbourhoodPlaces.length===0">No Images</div>
          <div class="neighbourhood" *ngIf="neighbourhoodPlaces.length>0">

              <div id="pnProductNav" class="wrapper-container">
                  <div id="pnProductNavContents" class="pn-ProductNav_Contents  places-container" *ngFor="let place of neighbourhoodPlaces">
                      <div class="dest-card" [style.background-image]="sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url('+ place.placePhoto + ')')">
                          <div class="content-container">
                              <div class="place-name">{{place.placeName}}</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

```html
user-landing-page.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Place } from 'src/app/models/place';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './user-landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-landing-page.component.css']
})

export class UserLandingPageComponent implements OnInit {
  // For longitude west, give in negative, for East, give in positive number.
  lat = 40.7127753;
  lng = -74.0059728;
  // loading: Boolean = true;

  neighbourhoodPlaces: Array<Place> = [];
  constructor() {
    this.neighbourhoodPlaces = new Array<Place>();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchNeighbourhood();
  }

  fetchNeighbourhood = () => {
    let map;
    let neighbourhoodService;
    const loc = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: loc,
      zoom: 15
    });

    const neighbourhoodRequest = {
      location: loc,
      radius: '1500',
      type: ['neighborhood', 'art_gallery', 'museum', 'zoo']
    };

    neighbourhoodService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    neighbourhoodService.nearbySearch(neighbourhoodRequest, (this.neighbourhoodCallback).bind(this));
  }
  neighbourhoodCallback = (results, status) => {
    let count = 0;
    results.forEach(element => {
      if (element.photos && count < 8) {
        count++;
        const newDest: Place = {
          placeName: element.name,
          placePhoto: (element.photos) ? element.photos[0].getUrl() : undefined
        };
        this.neighbourhoodPlaces.push(newDest);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
main index.html


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NgClusterCafe</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&language=en">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
tsconfig.app.json


/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["googlemaps"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using that `@types/googlemaps` may not be the best approached as I have encountered quite a few issues on it in my experience. Below is a sample that uses Places Nearby Search natively so you can follow Google Maps API official [documentations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests). Then you can use HTML 5 Geolocation to get the current location. Google Maps also has a sample using this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation?hl=en

Note: Aside from replacing the API Key placeholder in `index.html` file, you may encounter Google namespace is not defined. This is an issue with Stackblitz itself and can be easily fix by just putting, say, a blank space anywhere. This won't happen when implemented locally.

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nearby-search-micl24

**nearbySearch.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
    import { types } from './types/supportedTypes';
    import { type } from './types/types';
    declare const google: any;
    
    @Component({
      selector: "my-maps",
      templateUrl: "./nearbySearch.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./nearbySearch.component.css"]
    })
    export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild("map", { static: true }) mapElement: any;
      map: any; 
      latLng:string;
      radius:string;
      service;
      listOfTypes: type[] = types;
      infowindow;
      markers=[];
      types;
      bounds;
    
      constructor() {} 
      ngOnInit() {
        const mapProperties = {
          center: { lat: -33.8569, lng: 151.2152 },
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(
          this.mapElement.nativeElement,
          mapProperties
        );
      }
    
      onSubmit() {
        this.nearbySearch(this.latLng);
      }
    
      nearbySearch(latLng) {
        var latlngStr = this.latLng.split(',', 2);
        var latLngObj= {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    
        var request = {
          location: latLngObj,
          radius: this.radius,
          type: this.types
        };
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              this.createMarker(results[i]);
            }
            this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds);
          }
        });
      }
    
      createMarker(place) {
        this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: this.map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        this.markers.push(marker);
        marker.addListener('click',  () =>{
          this.infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          this.infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
        });
        this.bounds.extend(marker.position);
      }
    }
```

**nearbySearch.component.html**

```
    <h1 >Places API - Nearby Search: </h1>
    <b>Lat/ Lng: </b> <input placeholder="latitude, longitude" name="latLng" [(ngModel)]="latLng" required ><br/>
    <b>Radius: </b> <input placeholder="<=50 000" name="radius" [(ngModel)]="radius" required ><br/>
    <b>Type: </b> 
    <select name="types" [(ngModel)]="types">
      <option *ngFor="let type of listOfTypes" [value]="type.value">{{type.name}}</option>
    </select>
    
    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
    <div #map class="map"></div>
```

**index.html**

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <my-app>loading</my-app>
```